# pcl::MovingLeastSquares doesn't work

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I'm new to PCL and I'm trying to do this tutorial[here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/resampling.php#moving-least-squares). The problem is that I can compile it, but when I run this, it give me an error: *exception at 0x000007fefd27940d in pcl_VFHexperiment.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: pcl::IOException at memory location 0x001cf0e0*

I guess the problem is that *mls. process* function doesn't work correctly and the operation of file saving provides an error.
Could be the input file the problem? I use ism_test_cat.pcd file found [here](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/data/tree/master/tutorials). I don't know where the file suggested in the tutorial is. How should the input file be? 
Anyway I can see ism_test_cat.pcd file in the viewer following the other tutorial.

How to solve? Please help me.
I use VS2010, PCL 1.6, all 64bit

Thanks in advance a lots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"You should be able to find the input file at pcl/test/bun0.pcd."* It says in the tutorial.

Comment: [Google'd it and found it here] (https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/browser/stacks/point_cloud_perception/trunk/pcl/test?rev=28203)

Comment: I've just tried it, it doesn't work! It returns the same error! How could I solve this? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Hmmm ... I'm working on Ubuntu so I don't really know in you're case what could be the problem. Can you try it with another .pcd files from one of the exercises and come back?

Comment: thank you. I tried also with other ASCII files but nothing. Always the same problem. Should I try with binary files? I don't know where I can find it. Anyway, I noticed that error arises when it executes line 'pcl::io::savePCDFile ("bun0-mls.pcd", mls_points);' and not before

Comment: hmmm then can you check if you save the rigth thing, whatch out for the references. PCL sadly has manny tricks that hardens the use of it.

Comment: I've just tried to change file saving mode to 'savePCDFileASCII' and now it doesn't return an error. The file saved is different from input, probably there is information about normals. I don't know how to visualize it. But why  does 'savePCDFile' not work?

Comment: Can you re read? Use Rviz for visualising or pcl::visualizer!

Comment: My final purpose is to get meshes from point clouds. I don't still succeed. I am following this [tutorial](http://www.pointclouds.org/assets/icra2012/surface.pdf) but it doesn't work because it is not clear what is the input for pcl::MovingLeastSquares::process. For me it is not clear how to pass from 'PointXYZ' to 'PointXYZRGB' and so on.

Comment: Trying again with my original file [ism_test_cat.pcd](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/data/tree/master/tutorials) I received a new error when pcl::MovingLeastSquares::process function runs: 'Debug Error! Program:...  R6010-abort() has been called'. I'm using this settings: 'mls.setComputeNormals (true);
  mls.setInputCloud (cloud);
  mls.setSearchRadius (0.5);
  mls.setPolynomialFit (true);' What's on now?  Thank you

Comment: This is my [code](http://justpaste.it/dd14) which doesn't work as explained above

Comment: Also give at least a vote up for the response, if I helped you in any way.

Comment: I strongly wish, but I can't because it requires 15 reputation